# how do i convert this for loop to the correct while loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

this code i have typed in below is the original for loop

```
  String[][] wordData = {{"study", "consider", "examine", "learn"}, {"ponder", "read", "think", "cogigate"}};

int characterCount = 0;
for(String[] stringRow : wordData) {
    for(String s : stringRow) {
        characterCount += s.length();
    }
}
System.out.println(characterCount);
```

This is my attempt for the while loop

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
while(i<wordData.length) {
    j=0;
    while(j<wordData[i].length) {
        characterCount += wordData[j].length;
        System.out.print(characterCount);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `characterCount += wordData[j].length;` should be `characterCount += wordData[i][j].length;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate length of `word[i][j]` at each steps. Actually, word[j] is an array.

```
word[0] // {"study", "consider", "examine", "learn"}
word[1] // {"ponder", "read", "think", "cogigate"}
```

The correct way to implement this code with `while` is in this way.

```
int characterCount = 0;
int i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < wordData.length) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < wordData[i].length) {
        characterCount += (wordData[i][j]).length();
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
System.out.println(characterCount);
```

Just a little tiny thing, You have to print the result at the end, not in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] wordData = { {"study", "consider", "examine", "learn"}, {"ponder", "read", "think", "cogigate"}};
int characterCount = 0;
int i = 0;
while(i<wordData.length){
    int j = 0;
    while(j<wordData[i].length){
       characterCount += wordData[i][j].length();
       j++;
    }
    i++;
}

System.out.println(characterCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Converting `for` to `while`

You can convert any `for` loop to a `while` loop by just understanding how the `for` loop works. Here is a simple example:

```
for (A; B; C) {
    D;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
A;
while (B) {
    D;
    C;
}
```

---

However, in your specific case you are not using a *traditional for loop* but the **enhanced for loop**. Which, for *collections* (anything `Iterable`) is equivalent to using an `Iterator`:

```
// elements being a collection like List<E>
for (E element : elements) {
    ...
}
```

is the same as

```
Iterator<E> elementIter = elements.iterator();
while (elementIter.hasNext()) {
    E element = elementIter.next();
    ...
}
```

---

But, in your specific case you are using an enhanced for loop on an array. Which is converted to the traditional index-based for loop. So

```
// elements being an array like E[]
for (E element : elements) {
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    E element = elements[i];
    ...
}
```

which we can convert easily to a `while` loop as shown before:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < elements.length) {
    E element = elements[i];
    ...
    i++;
}
```

---

### Your code

That being said, lets take a look at your code now. Before we start thinking about your code in more detail, lets just blindly apply the above transformation:

First step, transforming the enhanced for loop to a traditional for loop:

```
String[][] wordData = {
    {"study", "consider", "examine", "learn"},
    {"ponder", "read", "think", "cogigate"}
};

int characterCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < wordData.length; i++) {
    String[] stringRow = wordData[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < stringRow.length; i++) {
        String s = stringRow[j];
        characterCount += s.length();
    }
}
System.out.println(characterCount);
```

And now the `while` loops:

```
String[][] wordData = {
    {"study", "consider", "examine", "learn"},
    {"ponder", "read", "think", "cogigate"}
};

int characterCount = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < wordData.length) {
    String[] stringRow = wordData[i];
    int j = 0;
    while (j < stringRow.length) {
        String s = stringRow[j];
        characterCount += s.length();
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
System.out.println(characterCount);
```

As you see, it is fairly easy.

---

### Streams

While we are at it, let me also show you a way how to solve your task using streams, because it is so short and elegant:

```
int characterCount = Stream.of(wordData) // Stream<String[]>
    .flatMap(Stream::of)                 // Stream<String>
    .mapToInt(String::length)            // IntStream
    .sum();
```

---

### Unicode

A final note about the pitfalls of Unicode. You are measuring `characterCount` using `String::length`. This will work for probably all cases you are interested in. However, for symbols that are *higher up* in the Unicode table, it will output incorrect values.

For example the string:

has a length of `4`. I am not kidding, `"".length()` returns `4` and not `2`.

This is because symbols like  or  actually need 2 `char`s to be represented. Unicode is a variable byte-length-encoding and hence not all symbols fit into the `16`-bit that Javas `char` use. So if you want that your code also works with such symbols, you have to use **code points** instead of simple plain *string length*.

Fortunately, it is still fairly simple to do this in Java. Here is the stream version that works for such inputs as well:

```
int characterCount = Stream.of(wordData)
    .flatMap(Stream::of)
    .mapToInt(s -> s.codePointCount(0, s.length())
    .sum();
```